# Add Fields to MongoDB Inner Object

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I'm trying to append fields to an object in my mongodb collection. So far this is what my document in MongoDB looks like.

[image]

My users can have multiple devices so I'm trying to append more fields to the devices object. I have tried to use $push for an array instead of an object but I didn't like how I would have to access the data later on when I retrieve it from the database.

So I started to use $set. $set works great because it gives me the format in which I want my data to save in the db but it will continually override my one key value pair in the devices object every time and I don't want that to happen.

**db.go**

```
func AddDeviceToProfile(uid string, deviceId int, deviceName string) {
    client := ConnectClient()
    col := client.Database(uid).Collection("User")

    idString := strconv.Itoa(deviceId)

    filter := bson.M{"uid": uid}

    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{"devices": bson.M{idString: deviceName}}, <------ Need to fix this 
    }

    option := options.FindOneAndUpdate()

    _ = col.FindOneAndUpdate(context.TODO(), filter, update, option)

    log.Print("Device Added")
    _ = client.Disconnect(context.TODO())
}
```

I have looked into using $addFields but I don't know if I was doing it correctly I just replaced $set above and added $addFields and I also tried it this way

```
update := bson.M{
        "devices": bson.M{"$addFields": bson.M{idString: deviceName}},
    }
```

What I want my document to look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using $push or $addFields what you need is $set directive.

To specify a field in an embedded document, use dot notation.

For the document matching the criteria _id equal to 100, the following operation updates the make field in the devices document:

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set: { "devices.make": "zzz" } }
)
```

Converting them to Go syntax is easy as well. What you are doing is correct. The following should work or might require a little bit of tweaking.

```
func AddDeviceToProfile(uid string, deviceId int, deviceName string) {
    client := ConnectClient()
    col := client.Database(uid).Collection("User")

    idString := strconv.Itoa(deviceId)

    filter := bson.M{"uid": uid}

    update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"devices." + idString: deviceName}}

    option := options.FindOneAndUpdate()

    _ = col.FindOneAndUpdate(context.TODO(), filter, update, option)

    log.Print("Device Added")
    _ = client.Disconnect(context.TODO())
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want, you completely omitted the idString that I would need later on. I updated the question with the image.

Comment: have closer look at the update command  @astronik. idString is there.

Comment: Yes yes, this is exactly it. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help @astronik . Please accept the answer if this solves your problem.